# ZeroMQ PUB/SUB filtering and performance

Tags: python, zeromq

I am trying to implement a broker using zeromq PUB/SUB(python eventlets). zeromq 2.1 does not seem to implement filtering at publisher and all messages are broadcasted to all subscribers which inturn apply filter. Is there some kind of workaround to achieve filtering at publisher. If not how bad is the performance if there are ~25 publishers and 25 subscribers exchanging msgs @ max rate of 200 msgs per second where msg_size ~= 5K through the broker.

Are there any opensource well-tested zero-mq broker implementations.??

Answer (score 3):

You have 3 questions:

- Can I filter myself at publisher? - yes
- How bad is the performance of sending 200 m/s to 25 nodes? - it depends on how large your messages are. But no, in that range of rates you would have no problems what so ever; problem comes when you start maxing out on IO throughput (1 gbit/s / 8 = 125 MiB/s. 125*.7 (verhead) = 87 MiB/s. 87 MiB / 5 KiB (per msg) = 17000 m/s. That's 712 msg/s per node before you start filling up your IO allowance. But then, if you are having this problem, you might as well just use PGM and do multicast at 17000 m/s.
- What about OSS ZMQ broker implementations? - they aren't existing afaik - but the guide describes how you can create a reliable "broker", with the [Majordomo pattern](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Service-Oriented-Reliable-Queuing-Majordomo-Pattern).

You would need to put more details in your question:

- Requirements?
- What's "bad performance" for you?
- Message size?
- Throughput requirements?
- Backbone speed (10 gbit/s)?

That said, if you need a broker, why don't you just use RabbitMQ and talk to RMQ as a ZMQ-device?

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question. I am expecting max_size ~= 5K. It may not be 25 different nodes. Some of the pub/sub services will be running in same node itself. How to filter at publisher itself using zeromq 2.1 native features ??

Answer (score 3):

zeromq 3.1 includes publish-side filtering.

zeromq includes the notion of a broker in what they call a device. You can set one up in ~3 lines of code. See http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Built-in-Devices

Answer (score 3):

From the ØMQ guide:

> From ZeroMQ v3.x, filtering happens at the publisher side when using a connected protocol (`tcp://` or `ipc://`). Using the `epgm://` protocol, filtering happens at the subscriber side. In ZeroMQ v2.x, all filtering happened at the subscriber side.